# Java using Map.Entry over a Map not compiling

Tags: java, dictionary

I am getting an error which I cannot seem to fix myself, it might be a stupid error, but I am unable to see it.

```
Map<TemplateBean, Map<String, String>> templateMap = new HashMap<>();
//some code that fills up the map
int biggestSize = 0;
Map<String, String> biggestValues = null;
for (Map.Entry<TemplateBean, Map<String, String>> entry : templateMap.values()) {
    Map<String, String> currentValues = entry.getValue();
    int currentSize = currentValues.size();
    if (currentSize > biggestSize) {
        biggestSize = currentSize;
        biggestValues = currentValues;
    }
}
if (biggestValues != null) {
    values = biggestValues;
}
```

It is giving this error on the for-loop:

```
incompatible types
  required: Entry<TemplateBean,Map<String,String>>
  found:    Map<String,String>
```

However I am pretty sure that I got it correct, I'm not new to iterating over the maps or anything, it is however still tuesday morning.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line -

```
for (Map.Entry<TemplateBean, Map<String, String>> entry: 
            templateMap.values())
```

to -

```
for (Map.Entry<TemplateBean, Map<String, String>> entry: 
            templateMap.entrySet())
```

Check out the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

Comment: Ahhh my variables were named something related to `values` all the time, hence why I appereantly choose `values()` wrongfully over `entrySet()`. Upvoting whenever it's possible.